# Lua: Can I select a table in script via argument in command line?

Tags: function, cmd, lua

I have a lua script with many tables like

```
local a = {1,2,3}
local b = {1,2,3}
local c = {1,2,3}
```

etc. and one function like

```
test = {}
function test.set(args)
    for x, y in pairs(args) do
    ....
    end
end

test[arg[1]](arg[2])
```

Now I want to choose one of the tables via command line to use it in the function. I tried

```
lua MyScript.lua set a
```

and I get the error

```
lua: MyScript.lua:1249: bad argument #1 to 'pairs' (table expected, got string)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'pairs'
    MyScript.lua:1249: in field '?'
    MyScript.lua:1266: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

It kind of makes sense because I pass a string. But I don't know how to select the table I want to use in the function. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
local all_your_tables = {a = {1,2,3}, b = {1,2,3}, c = {1,2,3}}
...
test[arg[1]](all_your_tables[arg[2]])
```